# How to make sure an android device application supports hardware feature

Tags: android, android-hardware

I am developing an application which uses camera extensively. What I wish to do is that if a device or tablet does not have camera it my application should not get installed on it.

Checked the `<uses-feature>` in android manifest but only checks when application is installed via android marketplace. What if I intend it to be also available my site. So is there a way I can handle this so that application should not get installed in case device does not have a camera hardware?

Thanks,
~nil

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to know if a device visits your website, does it have the required hardware (camera) to install the APK you're distributing?

Comment: No I want to detect when user is installing .apk? Cannot be sure that this will be hosted only my website, can be done on many others as well :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your manifest:

```
   <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
```

[uses-feature tag](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html)

Comment: But this check is applied if application is installed using Android Market otherwise if any user gets apk he can install it even though his device does not have camera.

Comment: have you verified that?  I would think you would get an installation error when the android:required flag is set to true.  If you can still install then I'm not sure there is a way to do what you are asking

Comment: Yes verified it and it does not give while installation even if device does not have a hardware support for the feature mentioned.

Comment: fair enough.  Then I am fairly certain there is no built in way to do what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use code to check device support feature :
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
if (!pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_SENSOR_COMPASS)) {
    // This device does not have a compass, turn off the compass feature
    disableCompassFeature();
}
preference link : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html#Features
```